# Why is BFS Approach showing time exceeded error in the question while DFS is not?

Tags: graph, time-complexity, big-o, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Why is BFS Approach showing time exceeded error in the following question while DFS is not ?
link to question : https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-closed-islands/description/

BFS Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int makeConnected(int n, vector<vector<int>>& connections) {
        unordered_map<int, list<int>> adj;

        for(auto edge: connections){
            adj[edge[0]].push_back(edge[1]);
            adj[edge[1]].push_back(edge[0]);
        }
        queue<int> q;
        vector<bool> visited(n,0);
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(!visited[i]) {q.push(i);
        count++;}

        while(!q.empty()){
            int front=q.front();
            visited[front] = true;
            q.pop();
            for(auto neighbour: adj[front]){
                if(!visited[neighbour]) q.push(neighbour);
            }
        }
        
        }
        if(connections.size()>=(n-1)){
            if(count==0)return 0;
            return count-1;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
};
```

DFS Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& grid, int row, int col) {
        int m = grid.size();
        int n = grid[0].size();

        if (row < 0 || row >= m || col < 0 || col >= n || grid[row][col] != 0) {
            return;
        }

        grid[row][col] = 1;  // Mark the cell as visited

        // Perform DFS on the neighboring cells
        dfs(grid, row - 1, col);
        dfs(grid, row + 1, col);
        dfs(grid, row, col - 1);
        dfs(grid, row, col + 1);
    }

    int closedIsland(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        int m = grid.size();
        int n = grid[0].size();
        int count = 0;

        // Perform DFS on the boundary cells
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            dfs(grid, i, 0);
            dfs(grid, i, n - 1);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            dfs(grid, 0, j);
            dfs(grid, m - 1, j);
        }

        // Count the number of closed islands
        for (int i = 1; i < m - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                    dfs(grid, i, j);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
};
```

I tried asking Chatgpt, It said that queue is incurring additional costs but later backed out when I asked the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(!visited[i]) {q.push(i);
        count++;}
```

What is this code doing?  You have just set every element of visited false, so why are you testing?

Notes:

- Please indent your code properly
- The 'graph' tag is wrong.  Did you not read the tag description?
- You need to tag with the coding language.

Comment: I have set all unvisited nodes as false initially, which gets set to true once they are traversed.

Comment: Isn't it how basic BFS is taught ?

Comment: But you are testing the value of every visited element before any traversing is done.  The test is redundant.

Comment: I shudder to think how BFS may be taught :-)